I have a web service that is using oracle apps cz cio import
I have an webservice which is deployed using axis and tomcat7 and jdk 1.7 but recently i have changed the versions to tomcat 9 and jdk 11 . after doing that i am getting exceptions as such for the imports that are already present in the webservice client classes .

Thu Jun 13 07:14:37 CEST 2024: Productxxxx.editxxxxxConfiguration: Exception : Cannot create or restore any configurations since the required engine libraries were not loaded.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create or restore any configurations since the required engine libraries were not loaded.
at oracle.apps.cz.cio.CIO.checkForCZLibraries(CIO.java:2526)
at oracle.apps.cz.cio.Configuration.(Configuration.java:377)

I tried changing the versions of tomcat and jdk and encountered this exceptions due to libraries for oracle.apps.cz.cio.CIO . What could be the possible solution and how shall i approach solving this issue .Do i need to import this libraries and if possible how do i do that . Any help would be very useful .few of the client classes which are required to use the CIO objects have this imports is it possible to add the libraries.I have went through oracle documentation as well .
